# How to set application which can suite any resolution of computer?

Tags: windows, winforms

I am working on C# win form. I created application in 1280 X 960 resolution.

But when i change system which have different resolution. it's not fit with that resolution.

My question is how to set application which can suite any resolution of computer ?

What should i do for that?

Comment: `What should i do for that?` - use WPF, which is resolution independent by default.

Comment: No, I can't migrate application from win form to WPF.

Answer (score 0):

If you are stuck with WinForms, you will want to get an understanding of all of the possible resolutions your customers might have.  You can then code your form so that it is optimized for the broadest resolution, but still usable by your lowest resolution customers.  You can make your forms a bit more dynamic by making use of the Dock property on your controls and using controls like SplitContainer and FlowLayoutPanel to segment the different areas of the form.  Though you should really strive to avoid it, you should also use panels to ensure your form scrolls if it will be cut off in very low resolutions.

All that being said, by nature WinForms is very non-dynamic and it can take a lot of effort to get it to be responsive to a lot of different resolutions.  If the spread between your minimum and maximum resolutions is not that great, then you can always just code and test to the lowest resolution.  Back in the day, I used to keep my second monitor set to 1024x768 just for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

While WPF will provide you with a truly resolution independent programming environment Windows Forms does have limited support for resolution independence.

[Automatic Scaling in Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229605%28VS.80%29.aspx)

> Automatic scaling enables a form and its controls, designed on one machine with a certain
>   display resolution or system font, to be displayed appropriately on
>   another machine with a different display resolution or system font. It
>   assures that the form and its controls will intelligently resize to be
>   consistent with native windows and other applications on both the
>   users' and other developers' machines. The support of the .NET
>   Framework for automatic scaling and visual styles enables .NET
>   Framework applications to maintain a consistent look and feel when
>   compared to native Windows applications on each user's machine.